# Why are my tabs being clipped on the right side, and how can I resolve this?

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabs

I have a tab control that is appearing like this, with the right side of each tab clipped:

[image: right side of each tab is clipped]

I can't figure out what to do to make it so the right side isn't clipped. At the moment I'm using a style definition with the following: `<Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,0,0" />`. If I set that to `Value="0,0,0,0"` then the margin appears correctly, as follows:

[image: correctly rounded corners]

but this won't work because I need to keep a 5px space between them.

For reference, this is the style I'm using:

```
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}" x:Key="TabControlStyle">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TabPanel Name="HeaderPanel" Grid.Row="0" Panel.ZIndex="1"  Margin="120,0,4,0" IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Background="Transparent" />
                    <Border Name="Border" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" >
                        <ContentPresenter Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" Margin="0" ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="TabItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="35" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Name="Border" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="{DynamicResource RedGradient}" CornerRadius="7,7,0,0" >
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" Margin="12,2,12,2"
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#ABABB2" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DarkRedColorBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#ABABB2" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is an example of how 1 of the tabs is implemented:

```
<TabControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            Style="{DynamicResource TabControlStyle}" SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">            
    <TabItem Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}" Name="tabCustomers" >
        <TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="/Resources/Images/TabMenuIcons/Folder.png" Stretch="None" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                <TextBlock Foreground="White">CUSTOMERS</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem.Header>

    </TabItem>
```

Comment: Did you try removing `<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />` from the style of tab item?

Comment: yeah, didn't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the HorizontalAlignment to be 'Center' instead of 'Left'

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="TabItemStyle">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change your Margin to

```
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Grid>
            <Border Name="Border" Margin="5,0,0,0" Background="Red" CornerRadius="7,7,0,0" >
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" Margin="12,2,12,2"
                    RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
```

in your TabItem ControlTemplate